# C Makefile - exec and object files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a .c file using makefile.txt with some gcc parameters.

I have the following Makefile:

```
 GCC_OPTIONS=-std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wextra -Wno-format-security -Werror -Werror=vla
        
        OBJS=driver.o q.o
        
        EXEC=q.out
        
        $(EXEC):$(OBJS)
        
            gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) $(OBJS) -o q.out -lm
        
        qdriver.o:qdriver.c q.h
        
            gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) -c qdriver.c -o qdriver.o    
        
        q.o:q.c q.h
        
            gcc $(GCC_OPTIONS) -c q.c -o q.o
        
        clean:
        
            rm $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

When I run make all I get the following error which I am not able to fix:

```
./makefile.txt: line 1: -pedantic-errors: command not found
: Permission deniede 2: ./q.o
./makefile.txt: line 4: EXEC: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 4: OBJS: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 4: $':\r': command not found
./makefile.txt: line 5: GCC_OPTIONS: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 5: OBJS: command not found
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./makefile.txt: line 6: qdriver.o:qdriver.c: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 7: GCC_OPTIONS: command not found
: No such file or directory
./makefile.txt: line 8: q.o:q.c: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 9: GCC_OPTIONS: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 10: $'clean:\r': command not found
./makefile.txt: line 11: OBJS: command not found
./makefile.txt: line 11: EXEC: command not found
rm: cannot remove ''$'\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please check the formatting of the Makefile in your question. By that I mean, that how it looks like in the question is identical to what you actually have. Makefiles (like Python) are whitespace and indentation sensitive, so if the formatting is off, this alone can cause problems.

Comment: Please show the command you invoked, not just the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you tried to run the makefile as a script -- If you type

```
GCC_OPTIONS=-std=c11 -pedantic-errors
```

at a bash prompt, it will give you the error

```
-pedantic-errors: command not found...
```

which implies that you are trying to run this as a line in bash.   I could see two ways this could happen:

1. you ran this as a bash script (i.e. you did something like `source makefile.txt` or `chmod +x makefile.txt; ./makefile.txt` instead of `make -f makefile.txt`
2. the first line actually has a tab in front of it, and there is a target specified beforehand as well, causing the first line (and subsequent lines) to be run as recipe lines.   You would have had to run with `make -i`, to make the output match what you posted though, as otherwise, it would quit after the first failure.

Either way, you have to fix the indentation in your makefile, as @datenwolf mentioned  -- leading tabs/spaces matter in makefiles